# After HalpStack is integrated when generating signed APK warnings are coming

Tags: android, proguard

As mentioned in title when generating signed APK following warning is coming.

```
 Warning:com.polites.android.MathUtils: can't find referenced method
'float sqrt(float)' in library class android.util.FloatMath
```

I try to write proguard rules but none is worked,i didn't find any proguard rules in HalpStack official github.

If any one knows regarding this warning please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this warning you can use following proguard rules.

```
-dontwarn com.polites.android.MathUtils**
-dontwarn com.polites.android.VectorF**
```

By placing this those warnings will not come.